# Use angularjs ng repeat $index to name model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I dont know anything about Angular but I need to put the $index number inside the ng-model and the src path (_XXX) but I dont know how to do it. I only need the $index number, Could you help me with this?

I tried to put {{$index}} but does not work...

```
<div ng-repeat='opt in el.options_final' for='radio{{$index}}'>
    <div class='img-radio'>
        <input id='image_location_{{$index}}' ng-model='el.image_XXX' />
        <img src='{{el.image_XXX}'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket, }, for the img src, el.image_XXX. That may help.

Comment: @ƊŗęДdϝulȻʘɗɇ that may not be enough i guess, needs to append index and ng-src is better than using src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for `ng-model`, `ng-model="el['image_' + $index]"` and similarly use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) and append index, `ng-src="{{el['image_' + $index]}}"`

```
<input id='image_location_{{$index}}' ng-model="el['image_' + $index]" />
<img ng-src="{{el['image_' + $index}}">
```

Why ng-src?

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: THANK YOU so much, I spend 8h trying to fix this (as I said: I dont know anything about angular), thanks!!